Calling `script` utility from .bashrc spoils Conda environment loading in VS Code
I added logging the terminal output to txt file, and this is enabled via a function in .bashrc:
start_terminal_logging()
{
    if [ -z "$SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE" ]; then
        # Log each session to a separate file:
        logdir=~/.terminal_logs
        logfile=$logdir/session_log_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_$$.txt
        # If no folder exist make one:
        if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
            mkdir -p $logdir
        fi
        export SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE=$logfile
        # Start logging, a=append, q=quiet:
        script -aq $logfile
        exit
    fi
}

# Start the logging(script above):
start_terminal_logging

This worked in normal bash terminal, but not in the VS Code terminal, so I moddified user's settings.json to reset the variable which was causing problems to VS Code (it was inherited from the environment I guss, so I reset it):
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE": null,
    }

This worked, and now logging from VS Code terminal is OK too, however, after I added this, the Conda evnironment is not automatically started in VS Code as it used to. What could be the problem?

I don't understand your question.

Rephrased as :
Does the problem exist with any variable used inside of "terminal.integrated.env.linux" or just specifically SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE? Try replacing SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE with SOMETHING_OTHER_VAR_NAME.

@shellter Turns out your question is to the point. This happpens only when SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE is reset, so I need to add some info to the question. I (wrongly) asumed this variable has nothing to do with Conda, but...

start_terminal_loggingstarts an entirely new session; is this really part of your .bashrc? Also the exit looks decidedly misplaced.

@tripleee Not sure where to place it if not in the .bashrc. I might give up the terminal logging thing altogether, even it's sometimes invaluable...

Your question is not clear as written, so I'm not entirely sure what you're after.  That said, the issue might be a problem between interactive vs. non-interactive shells.
When Bash runs a full interactive login shell, it normally executes ~/.bash_login, and when it runs non-interactively (such as from a crontab, or other background process) it sources ~/.bashrc.  This is why you shouldn't include text output in your ~/.bashrc, or it may end up in some random log file for a background process!
If your issue is that you don't want your script to run for these background processes, but you do want it to run on a regular login shell, just put your code into ~/.bash_login and you're done.
If this doesn't solve it, please explain the problem more specifically.
